# how to pass "-i" to a python script that reads in other arguments

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

A normal python script that does not need extra arguments from the command line can be executed passing `-i` to enter python upon completion. I was wondering what to do when my script reads in multiple other arguments using `sys.argv` if I want to enter python upon completion as well? Because at the moment it returns error of the arguments being read. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works fine:

```
python -i myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Example:

```
nosklo@stackoverflow:~$ touch foobar.py # create empty file
nosklo@stackoverflow:~$ python -i foobar.py arg1 arg2
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
['foobar.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```